# Get correct data from JsonObject

Tags: java, json, wcf

Get correct data from JsonObject..

This is how the jsonstring looks like:

```
[
  {
    "EditLink": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/Service.svc\/A?format=json",
    "Item": { "Value": "A" }
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/Service.svc\/B?format=json",
    "Item": { "Value": "B" }
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/Service.svc\/C?format=json",
    "Item": { "Value": "C" }
  }
]
```

How is it possible to get the Values only?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  With what are you trying to get the values?  C#? Javascript?

Comment: So pick your library to parse the JSON and then... the rest is as easy as making a box cake. You may be able to find a library with "selector" support, or else it will just be a simple tree traversal along said structure above. (Java is not the most "compact" language for dealing with data-structures.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a collection of values, you can write a routine to do that:

```
function getItems(jsonArray) {
    var list = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
       list.push(jsonArray[i].Item.Value);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) 1.6, you could get values like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
List<JsonNode> values = root.findValues("Value");
// or if you want values as String, use "findValuesAsText" to get List<String>
```

and you can access specific type (number, boolean, etc) via JsonNode accessors.